# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Files not showing up in Nautilus, but can find using "locate" command

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, files, locate

My Downloads folder is showing nothing right now( it was working perfectly earlier), and when I try to find a file using

> locate -i

which is in my downloads folder, it shows the path correctly, but when I try to view the downloads folder, it's empty!

The "ls -a" command doesn't show any of my files either.
Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

In doubt you may try to find out how locate works. Using "man locate" the third parapraph tells you that locate might give you answers for files that do not exist any longer. Try updatedb and I'm pretty sure you won't find that entry.